# Cookieless Client Side Tracking in GA4

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, gtag.js

Is there a simple way to implement the previously possible UA cookie less tracking in GA4 without server side tracking?

My UA code:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-myid', {
  'anonymize_ip': true,
  'client_storage': 'none',
  'client_id': 'my_client_id
});
```

So if I do something similar in GA4 with the new script, it does not track users

```
gtag('consent', 'default', {
  'ad_storage': 'denied',
  'analytics_storage': 'denied',
  'functionality_storage': 'denied',
  'personalization_storage': 'denied',
  'security_storage': 'denied'
});

gtag('config', 'G-myid', {
  'user_id': 'my_user_id',
  'client_id': 'my_client_id'
});
```

Is there anything that can be done to enable client side tracking without cookies using my own ids?

Answer (score 0):

You must have `analytics_storage`: *true*. So you have to manage consent mode according to your needs or remove it if not necessary. It depends also on how you manage the cookie policy with respect to current legislation.